# Is this a correct way to choose the appropriate number of communities in networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have a graph `g` and I want to use [fluid communities algorithm](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.asyn_fluid.asyn_fluidc.html) and [Girvan-Newman method](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.centrality.girvan_newman.html) to detect communities in `g`. My predetermined number of communities is one of `[2, 3, 4, 5]`. To choose the best number of communities `best_k`, I use [quality coverage](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.quality.coverage.html).

Because Girvan-Newman method returns `best_k = 2` in which one community contains only `3` nodes. I suspect I did something wrong. Could you please check if I implement the methods correctly?

```
import urllib3
import io
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import community
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Import dataset
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/lesmis.gml'
f = http.request('GET', url)
data = io.BytesIO(f.data)
g = nx.read_gml(data)

## Define a function to add community attributes
def add_att(g, att, att_name):
    att = list(att)
    for i in g.nodes:
        for j in range(len(att)):
            if i in list(att[j]):
                nx.set_node_attributes(g, {i: j}, name = att_name)
                break            

list_k = [2, 3, 4, 5]
best_k = 2
qua_cov = 0

## Fluid communities algorithm
for k in list_k:
    fluid = community.asyn_fluid.asyn_fluidc(g, k) # fluid is the partition of nodes
    fluid = list(fluid)
    cur_qua_cov = community.quality.coverage(g, fluid) # compute quality coverage
    if cur_qua_cov >= qua_cov:
        qua_cov = cur_qua_cov
        best_k = k

commu_fluid = community.asyn_fluid.asyn_fluidc(g, best_k)
            
## Girvan-Newman method
commu_gn = community.centrality.girvan_newman(g) 
commu_gn = list(commu_gn) # commu_gn is the list of partitions of nodes
best_k = 2
qua_cov = 0

for k in list_k:
    cur_qua_cov = community.quality.coverage(g, commu_gn[k - 2])
    if cur_qua_cov >= qua_cov:
        qua_cov = cur_qua_cov
        best_k = k

commu_gn = commu_gn[best_k - 2]

## Add attributes
att = [commu_fluid, commu_gn]
att_name = ['commu_fluid', 'commu_gn']
for i in range(len(att)):
    add_att(g, att[i], att_name[i])
```